# Strange Multiple Definitions Error

Tags: c++

I have something like this in my code:

```
namespace A {
namespace B {

void
GetLine(std::istream& stream, std::string& line)
{
    line.clear();
    while (stream.good()) {
        std::getline(stream, line);
        boost::trim(line);
        if (not line.empty()) break;
    }
    boost::to_upper(line);
}

}
}
```

And I get multiple definition error whenever I call `A::B::GetLine`. Any Ideas why?

(The code is at work, so I will try to give out specific snippets if you need more info, but I can't just pase the entire code here).

Comment: Can't you post the compiler error message? Perhaps it will hint us at something else that is not in the snippet above.

Comment: Are you trying to link in the object file multiple times? Take a look at your makefile to see if the .o containing this function is being passed to the compiler multiple times. I'm assuming you're on a unix or unix-like system, but another thing you could do is run "nm --demangle" on all of your object files and search for A::B::GetLine to see if it shows up as "defined" in multiple .o files.

Comment: +1 for the nm --demangle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost certainly included the code in multiple headers, rather than declaring in a header and defining in a source file. You need to declare the function inline, template it, or move the definition into a source file but leave the declaration in a header.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you probably have this code in a .h file and include it into more .cpp files. The solution is to use inline keyword to make the compiler inline it and remove the reference:

```
namespace A {
namespace B {

inline void
GetLine(std::istream& stream, std::string& line)
{
    line.clear();
    while (stream.good()) {
        std::getline(stream, line);
        boost::trim(line);
        if (not line.empty()) break;
    }
    boost::to_upper(line);
}

}
}
```

Another solution is to move the method body to a .cpp file.